# Python xmlrpc server in windows

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I'm looking for a library that can help me build a good XMLRPC server in Python that could run on Windows. The SimpleXMLRPCServer class looks fine but I don't know if it will suit all my needs, since I'd like to be able to connect from multiple clients at the same time. I found [this](http://github.com/lionelyoung/twisted-secure-xmlrpc) on GitHub, but I don't know if it'll work.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) for XMLRPC using the built-in tool/dispatcher, and it runs on Windows as far as I know.

But you really need to ask yourself why you want to do RPC vs. a RESTful service in 2010.  XMLRPC is very limited in the variable types allowed, and adds significant encapsulation overhead, and requires a client that can talk XMLRPC.

Answer (score 1):

I also like CheeyPy, but have also used Twisted for such needs.  Pretty simple to use and Twisted has defereds and helper functions like deferToThread and callLater to allow for blocking code to act in a non-blocking fashion.

Take a look at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/xmlrpc.html for a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [circuits](http://bitbucket.org/prologic/circuits/) for stuff like this (*but it's not for everyone*). There's a simple example in the examples/web/ directory in the source repository.